# iOS chromecast sdk 4.4.4 Volume issue

Tags: ios, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I have upgraded the app with cast sdk iOS 4.4.4. Found the below issue.
Press the hardware volume 'Up' button in iPhone - the volume on the receiver goes down. Has anybody encountered similar issue? Any workaround for this.

Answer (score 1):

We have a fix for this and will be release with our next SDK release. As of now we don't have exact date, please do sign up for this google group to get notified when the release happens.

https://developers.google.com/cast/support#news_and_announcements